# Android Studio - Genymotion - Volley gets wrong url to download

Tags: android, android-volley, genymotion

I'm facing this really strange issue and I couldn't realize what's happening. 
I have a login activity and when I try to make a request to validate the user information, I get this error in `volley`:

> com.android.volley.NoConnectionError: java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "teste.escolaemmovimento.com.br": No address associated with hostname.

This error only happens when I'm using the `Genymotion` emulator, I verify the URL field inside of the `volley Request` object right after create that and after insert the request in the `volley queue` and the correct url is there. 
(when I test in the device this error does not happens.)

**LogCat:**

```
06-01 13:17:28.351  25469-25521/br.com.escolaemmovimento D/OpenGLRenderer﹕             Render dirty regions requested: true
06-01 13:17:28.362  25469-25469/br.com.escolaemmovimento D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xabb84990, tid 25469
06-01 13:17:28.374  25469-25469/br.com.escolaemmovimento D/Atlas﹕ Validating map...
06-01 13:17:28.556  25469-25521/br.com.escolaemmovimento D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
06-01 13:17:28.557  25469-25521/br.com.escolaemmovimento D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
06-01 13:17:28.568  25469-25521/br.com.escolaemmovimento D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so
06-01 13:17:28.578  25469-25521/br.com.escolaemmovimento D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xaf60b940, tid 25521
06-01 13:17:28.604  25469-25521/br.com.escolaemmovimento I/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Initialized EGL, version 1.4
06-01 13:17:28.635  25469-25521/br.com.escolaemmovimento D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
06-01 13:17:28.650  25469-25521/br.com.escolaemmovimento W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
06-01 13:17:28.651  25469-25521/br.com.escolaemmovimento W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xaf639400, error=EGL_SUCCESS
06-01 13:17:54.808  25469-25469/br.com.escolaemmovimento I/System.out﹕ com.android.volley.NoConnectionError: java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "teste.escolaemmovimento.com.br": No address associated with hostname
```

Anyone has already faced this issue? This is a problem only associate with the emulator? Thanks for any help.

Comment: do you have the internet permission in the manifest ?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes, i have the permission set in the manifest. This issue only occurs when i'm using the emulator, the same test using a device works fine. 
The main problem is that volley request is changing the url atribb without a reason that a could find.

Comment: You should also enable `ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE` just in case.

Answer (score 0):

`UnknownHostException` is thrown to indicate that the IP address of a host could not be determined. Make sure you have internet access inside of Genymotion.